# what are the limitations of asp.net MVC 2 with asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on asp.net MVC . but I just want to know what are the limitations of the asp.enr mvc 2

Comment: Limitations in what respect?  Compared to what?  Its a web application framework.  You are limited to what can be delivered over the web.

Comment: as compare to asp.net only. I want to understand the scope on asp.net MVC 2. means what is possible as compare to pure asp.net in asp.net MVC 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is perfectly capable to run enterprise web sites and so forth. There is no limits, and it's not like it's "only suited for small sites" or anything like that.

People say that ASP.NET MVC is generally faster than normal ASP.NET Webforms, but I don't have any data on that. Webforms (proberbly what you call "pure asp.net"), you use a abstraction over the web, that makes it easier for people that have made windows apps, to build for the web. Both are very fast, if you use them the right way, so this is not really an argument, but a proof that MVC is geared for big sites.

If you are new in the business, or have experience in other web languages, then I will say that MVC is the best bet for you. It looks alot like other web frameworks, where webforms is one of a kind.

In both solutions you still have access to the whole of the .NET framework.

Hope this helps a bit. :)

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC is built on top of ASP.NET so everything you could do in ASP.NET could be done with ASP.NET MVC. In addition to this it allows clearer separation of concerns, more easily unit testable code, better control of the generated HTML.